# docker : invalid reference format on Synology NAS

Tags: docker, synology

I keep getting, "docker: invalid reference format" when I am running a script to add tinymediamanager to my Synology NAS. I have run this script before and it worked. All I changed was to add another source. Please help if able. The original build was from https://mariushosting.com/how-to-install-tinymediamanager-on-your-synology-nas/

```
docker run -d --name=tinymediamanager \
-p 4121:4000 \
-e USER_ID=1026 \
-e GROUP_ID=100 \
-e TZ=America/Chicago \
-v /volume1/docker/tinymediamanager:/data \
-v /volume3/Movies:/1_movies \
-v /volume3/Movie Editions:/2_editions \
-v /volume3/TV-Shows:/3_tvshows \
-v /volume3/Workout Programs:/4_workout \
-v /volume1/docker/tinymediamanager/addons:/app/addons \
--restart always \
tinymediamanager/tinymediamanager
```

Reviewed script for common errors. Followed guide https://ioflood.com/blog/solved-docker-invalid-reference-format-causes-and-solutions/. Tried just removing what I added but script suddenly doesn't work anymore.

Comment: `Editions:/2_editions` is not a valid image name. See the linked question for details on quoting your CLI args.